# whats faster java if\else or sql case when

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a query which returns thousands of records (at some point it will).  In that query I have some like this

```
Case when column in(:params1)
then :param2
when column in (:params3)
then :param4
when column in(:params5)
then :param6
when column in(:params7)
then :param8
END ABC
```

Now the question is what is better to do this in the query or return the column value and do the if\else in the pojo?  And why? I tried testing it but currently don't have that much data.

Comment: Can you explain the Table and show the concrete Query?

Comment: So create some completely random data! Better still, create some random realistic data!

Comment: See http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/iblog/architecture/C465799452/E20070322201220/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is better (both because of performance and complexity) to let the database do as much work as possible for you. Doing the work in your application is likely to incur more network traffic than is necessary (which would decrease performance) and the code would have to contain all the nasty logic in it which would add complexity.

Also remember to [avoid premature optimization](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=331531). Try to avoid fixing problems that you don't have yet.

I would recommend letting the database do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Returning thousands of records to the middle tier, operating on them, and shoving the result back into the database makes no sense to me.  Why do all that network back and forth?

If you are truly processing that many records, I'd recommend considering letting the database do the work.  No network traffic that way.

If not possible, you should make sure you truly need all those records.  I'm betting you only think you do.

Writing queries this way seems like another bad idea to me.

Comment: I think its best you understand the issue.  I am not returning this to the middle tier, I am not shoving the results back into the database. I yes I do think I need all these records.  The Application is a batch that picks up records that changed for the day and sends it to an interface partner.  So all those records are needed.

Comment: That's fine.  I still think that's an awful query.

Comment: So can you please give me a better idea then what I am doing.  I need to get all the records and print them to the file

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?  You've provided next to nothing to go on.  You assume - incorrectly - that I'm willing to spend a lot of time on this.  Why is that?